# using bcp to export data to text fie with c#

Tags: c#, sql, bcp

this is my .bat file it works in command prompt but in my c# code it dose not work: 
this the .bat file code:

```
bcp "select * from %4.att.Attendance where Date <= '%5' " queryout  "Attendance.txt"  -c  -b  200000 -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 
bcp "select * from %4.att.PairedAttendnce where Date <= '%5' " queryout "PairedAttendnce.txt"  -c -b 200000 -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 
bcp "select * from %4.att.PersonDateStructure where Date <= '%5' " queryout "PersonDateStructure.txt"  -c -b 200000 -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 
bcp "select * from %4.att.dailyResult where Date <= '%5' " queryout "DailyResult.txt"  -c -b 200000 -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 
bcp "select * from %4.att.WPResult where WPID  <= %7  " queryout "WPResult.txt  "  -c -b 200000 -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 
bcp "select * from %4.att.BaseResultCredit where date <= '%5'" queryout "BaseResultCredit.txt"  -c -b 200000 -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 
bcp "select * from %4.att.Credit where StartDate <= '%5' " queryout "Credit.txt"  -c -b 200000 -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 
bcp "select * from %4.Wfo.nwfDoc where SDate  <= '%5'" queryout "nwfDoc.txt"  -c -b 200000 -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 
bcp "select * from %4.Sec.Eventlog where REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CreateDateTime, 120), 10), '-', '/') <= '%6' " queryout "Eventlog.txt"  -c -b 200000 -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 
bcp "select * from %4.Cms.DDLLog where  REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,  PostTime, 120), 10), '-', '/')  <= '%6' " queryout "DDLLog.txt"  -c -b 200000 -S %1 -U %2 -P %3
```

and this is the c# code :

```
 string MyBatchFile = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\BatchFiles\Export.bat";

            var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            DateTime dt =  PersianDate.ConvertDate.ToEn (dateOfArchive);

            process.StartInfo.FileName = MyBatchFile;
            // process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\"", serverDBIP, ServerDbUserName, ServerDbPassword, ServerDBName, dateOfArchive, dt.ToShortDateString(), wpid);
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\"\"{1}\"\"{2}\"\"{3}\"\"{4}\"\"{5}\"\"{6}\"",
            serverDBIP, ServerDbUserName, ServerDbPassword, ServerDBName, dateOfArchive,dt.ToShortDateString(), wpid);

            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            bool b = process.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            //string errorMessage = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();

            //string outputMessage = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            //process.WaitForExit();    
            process.Close();
            return b;
```

does any body know why the code does not work?

Comment: "does not work" is not an error message or problem statement. Please give full, clear, detailed information about what is happening.

Comment: i mean the text file have not been create after executing the code

Comment: are you getting error? there must be something. We cannot help you like this.. we need to have more information abot the context

Comment: Please edit the question to include any extra information you have. We'll need quite a lot more than that. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand the kind of information you might want to include, and how to structure your question. We'd like to help you, but we can't without knowing a lot more. Remember: we can't read your screen, your disk...or your mind! Thanks.

Comment: unfortunatly i dont get any error or exeption

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your file is created under `process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` (which is default right now)

You need to set

```
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = <your-working-dir>
```

in order to be able to save your batch results in a given directory.

Comment: when i run the code in command prompt it works and txt file will be created, the directory is correct

Comment: Oh man! Your application is not aware of your working directory. you need to make your application aware of your WorkingDirectory

Comment: but how? i tried the above code but it did not work for me? help please

Comment: what should i write instead of  process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = <your-working-dir> ? i have defined the batch file address here: string MyBatchFile = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\BatchFiles\Export.bat";

Comment: just `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and then look under that directory